# Can you omit PDO prepare if there's no placeholder/dynamic data in a query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on an application at the moment that uses PDO with a MySQL database.

I'm seeing some queries, which are just very simple `SELECT` statements, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC
```

The code does **not** use `prepare`, for example:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $this->table . " ORDER BY name ASC";
    $stmt = $this->db->query($sql);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $results;
```

Is it ok to do this, i.e. without using prepare, if there's no placeholders in the query?

The reason I've asked this is because according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) it says

> The SQL statement can contain **zero** or more named (:name) or question mark (?) parameter markers

which makes me wonder why you'd use this in the case of having no (*zero*) parameter markers?

Comment: ............yes

Comment: ... although you may want to escape the table name with backticks.

Comment: @JonStirling you seem to imply that this is "obvious". However, if one is not intensely familiar with prepared statements, one might think that the `prepare()` function does other things beside preparing placeholders, especially since the documentation mentions *zero* or more placeholders. I think it is a pretty legitimate question.

Comment: @Pete The `.` are because there is a minimum comment length.

Comment: @JonStirling Ah I forgot that that might be the case, my apologies :)

Comment: @Pete No probs :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the use of prepared statements have 2 main causes:

1. Enhance running the same query with different parameters.
2. Prevent sql injection by separating sql code from the parameters.

Since you have no parameters that could be handled by a prepared statement (table names cannot be a parameter), you do not gain anything by pushing the query through as a prepared statement.

You still need to make sure that whatever is returned by `$this->table` will not cause any issues with the generated sql code.

Comment: please could you clarify "You still need to make sure that whatever is returned by $this->table will not cause any issues with the generated sql code.". In the example above it returns an array of the data in a table with the array keys matching the field names and the data being the data in the table.

Comment: You are using string concatenation to create a full sql query. If `$this->table` returns something that can be interpreted as and sql command, then you can still fall victim to an sql injection attack.

Comment: ok thanks. In this case it doesn't because it is simply a table name defined in a class `protected $table = 'my_table'`

Comment: Yeah, it's a common pitfall to assume that whatever data is stored in the database, it is correct. You should do some reading around 2nd order sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can omit `prepare` if there is no dynamic data in your query.
But prepared statements have more advantages than only securing your queries.

According to http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php a second advantage is, that statements can be prepared once and executed multiple times.

> The query only needs to be parsed (or prepared) once, but can be executed multiple times with the same or different parameters. When the query is prepared, the database will analyze, compile and optimize its plan for executing the query. For complex queries this process can take up enough time that it will noticeably slow down an application if there is a need to repeat the same query many times with different parameters. By using a prepared statement the application avoids repeating the analyze/compile/optimize cycle. This means that prepared statements use fewer resources and thus run faster.

Nevertheless, if you run your query only once and there is no dynamic data inside your query, omitting `prepare` is also fine.

Comment: Can you remember  a single case when you had to run a query like "SELECT * FROM table" more than once?

Comment: If you run **exactly** the same query multiple times, then caching is probably a better option to speed up the query, than using a prepared statement.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Of course not - but i tried to give point out, that there are more advantages of prepared statements than only escaping parameters. Sometimes your comments are really unnecessary attacks with no additional value to anyone my friend ;)

Comment: @Shadow if the **exact** same query is executed multiple times, the result is expected to be the same (if there are no write operations in background in the meantime) - therefore caching the result will be most effective and also avoids unnecessary database interaction at all

Comment: @chris85 of course you're right ;) Edited my answer

Comment: You see, your answer makes an emphasis, while the real issue is so negligible that it hardly worth mentioning at all.

Comment: Maybe for you it's negligible. For others it isn't i think - otherwise the question wouldn't have appeared. Be glad that you know it already - I'm here to help people if I can. And a little bit of background knowledge never hurt anyone ;)

Comment: FWIW the more information the better - I've learned something from every comment on here, and all this information is useful. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In reality, you have to run such a query extremely seldom. A few tables with configuration-like options may be.

In all other cases at least LIMIT clause is obligatory.

So the question is rather a theoretical one.